# Optional Message Parts in WSDL

Tags: soap, wsdl

In my wsdl:message i got two parameters, firstname and lastname:

```
<message name="setName">
  <part name="firstname" type="xsd:string"></part>
  <part name="lastname" type="xsd:string"></part>
</message>
```

I want to define the "firstname" part as required, and the "lastname" part as optional. 
How do i do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In WSDL parts can not be optional. They are always required. If you need optional parts, you will have to create one part that refers to a XSD complexType that then can have optional elements.

Comment: Example ? Nobody which is new to this topic can  understand what you mean

Comment: Example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179098/soap-ws-make-webparam-optional/21181974

Answer (score 5):

You can add *nullable* to *lastname*, so *firstname* is required:

```
<message name="setName">
    <part name="firstname" type="xsd:string"></part>
    <part name="lastname" xsi:nil="true" type="xsd:string"></part>
</message>
```

If you do so, your soap body look like this *(empty or filled lastname*):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:user="http://www.example.com/MyService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <user:setName>
         <firstname>John</firstname>
         <lastname></lastname>
      </user:setName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Or even without *lastname*:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:user="http://www.example.com/MyService/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <user:setName>
         <firstname>John</firstname>
      </user:setName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You will have to add the namespace definition `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to your WSDL for `xsi:nil` to be understood.

Comment: W/o lastname, does not seem to work, at least using Apache CXF.

Comment: Is it OK to write `<lastname></lastname>`, or do you have to write `<lastname xsi:nil="true"></lastname>` ?