# Repeating message part in WSDL message?

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I am consuming a web service where parts of the WSDL looks like this:

```
<wsdl:message name='FooResponse'>
    <wsdl:part name='parameters' element='tjsr:FooResponse' />
</wsdl:message>
```

The FooReponse type is defined in a separate xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="FooResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FooBaz" type="core:FooBaz" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Does the response always contain exactly one FooResponse, or can the message contain zero or multiple FooResponse?

(Yes, I understand that the FooResponse itself can contain any number of FooBaz)

Comment: Here is a related question, which answers half of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324847/optional-message-parts-in-wsdl

Comment: Do you specify, anywhere in your xsd the element with name `FooResponse`? In your question you've included the type with name `FooResponse` but where is the element?